# RadComboBox with Checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm attempting to create groups of check boxes in a RadComboBoxItem. When the click group 1 i want all of group 1 to be selected and same for group 2 along with a check all.(However i want to be able to style the check all so I've made it an extra option). So this all works fine, my only issue is that when one option is selected it closes the dropd down... How can i keep it from doing so?

combo box:

```
   EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True" DropDownWidth="380px">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" BackColor="Gray" ForeColor="White" 
                     Owner="txtAlertType" Text="Check All" Value="0" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Stop Payment Submitted" 
            Value="13" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" BackColor="DarkGray" IsSeparator="True" 
            Owner="txtAlertType" Text="Custom Alerts" Value="0" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Login" Value="12" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Matures in X Days" Value="1" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" BackColor="DarkGray" IsSeparator="True" 
            Owner="txtAlertType" Text="Cash Management" Value="0" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Payment Due in X Days" 
            Value="2" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Batch Approved" Value="21" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Balance &gt; $" Value="3" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Batch Prossed" Value="22" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Balance &lt; $" Value="4" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Positive Pay Exception" 
            Value="25" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Pending ACH" Value="5" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Bank Received Wire &gt; $" 
            Value="24" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Balance Alert" Value="6" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Wire Approved" Value="23" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Check # Cleared" Value="7" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Wire Submitted &gt; $" 
            Value="26" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Deposit &gt; $" Value="8" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Wire Transfer Rejected by User" 
            Value="27" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Debit &gt; $" Value="9" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Wire Transfer Rejected by Bank" 
            Value="28" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="NSF Items Today" Value="10" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Wire Transfer Deleted by User" 
            Value="29" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" 
            Text="Online Transaction Processed" Value="11" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Wire Transfer Deleted by Bank" 
            Value="30" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub OnItemChecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RadComboBoxItemEventArgs)

    Select Case e.Item.Text
        Case "Check All"
            If e.Item.Checked = True Then
                For i = 0 To txtAlertType.Items.Count() - 1
                    txtAlertType.Items(i).Checked = True
                Next
            Else
                For i = 0 To txtAlertType.Items.Count() - 1
                    txtAlertType.Items(i).Checked = False
                Next
            End If

        Case "Custom Alerts"
            If e.Item.Checked = True Then
                For i = 0 To txtAlertType.Items.Count() - 1
                    If txtAlertType.Items(i).value < 14 And txtAlertType.Items(i).value > 0 Then
                        txtAlertType.Items(i).Checked = True
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                txtAlertType.Items(0).Checked = False
                For i = 0 To txtAlertType.Items.Count() - 1
                    If txtAlertType.Items(i).value < 14 And txtAlertType.Items(i).value > 0 Then
                        txtAlertType.Items(i).Checked = False
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Case "Cash Management"
            If e.Item.Checked = True Then
                For i = 0 To txtAlertType.Items.Count() - 1
                    If txtAlertType.Items(i).value > 15 Then
                        txtAlertType.Items(i).Checked = True
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                txtAlertType.Items(0).Checked = False
                For i = 15 To txtAlertType.Items.Count() - 1
                    If txtAlertType.Items(i).value > 15 Then
                        txtAlertType.Items(i).Checked = True
                    End If
                Next
            End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i ended up doing:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="txtAlertType" Runat="server" Visible="False" OnClientItemChecked="OnClientDropDown"
                    Width="205px" AutoPostBack="True" CheckBoxes="True"  DropDownCssClass="multipleRowsColumns"
                    EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True" DropDownWidth="400px">

function OnClientDropDown(sender, eventArgs) {
    if (eventArgs.get_item().get_text() == "Custom Alerts") {
        var Combo = $find("<%=txtAlertType.ClientID %>");
        var items = Combo.get_items();
        var i = 2;
        if (items._array[i].get_checked()) {
            var combo = $find("<%= txtAlertType.ClientID %>");
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            combo.trackChanges();
            combo.get_items().getItem(1).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(3).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(4).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(6).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(8).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(10).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(12).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(14).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(16).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(18).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(20).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(22).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(24).check();
            combo.commitChanges();
        } else {
           var combo = $find("<%= txtAlertType.ClientID %>");
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            combo.trackChanges();
            combo.get_items().getItem(1).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(3).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(4).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(6).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(8).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(10).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(12).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(14).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(16).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(18).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(20).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(22).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(24).uncheck();
            combo.commitChanges();
        }
    }

    if (eventArgs.get_item().get_text() == "Cash Management") {
        var Combo = $find("<%=txtAlertType.ClientID %>");
        var items = Combo.get_items();
        var i = 5;
        if (items._array[i].get_checked()) {
            var combo = $find("<%= txtAlertType.ClientID %>");
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            combo.trackChanges();
            combo.get_items().getItem(7).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(9).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(11).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(13).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(15).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(17).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(19).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(21).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(23).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(25).check();
            combo.commitChanges();
        } else {
            var combo = $find("<%= txtAlertType.ClientID %>");
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            combo.trackChanges();
            combo.get_items().getItem(7).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(9).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(11).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(13).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(15).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(17).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(19).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(21).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(23).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(25).uncheck();
            combo.commitChanges();
        }
    }

    if (eventArgs.get_item().get_text() == "Check All") {
        var Combo = $find("<%=txtAlertType.ClientID %>");
        var items = Combo.get_items();
        var i = 0;
        if (items._array[i].get_checked()) {
            var combo = $find("<%= txtAlertType.ClientID %>");
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            combo.trackChanges();
            combo.get_items().getItem(1).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(2).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(3).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(4).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(6).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(8).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(10).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(12).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(14).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(16).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(18).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(20).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(22).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(24).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(5).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(7).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(9).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(11).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(13).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(15).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(17).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(19).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(21).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(23).check();
            combo.get_items().getItem(25).check();
            combo.commitChanges();
        } else {
            var combo = $find("<%= txtAlertType.ClientID %>");
            var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();
            combo.trackChanges();
            combo.get_items().getItem(1).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(2).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(3).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(4).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(6).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(8).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(10).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(12).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(14).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(16).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(18).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(20).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(22).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(24).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(5).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(7).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(9).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(11).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(13).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(15).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(17).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(19).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(21).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(23).uncheck();
            combo.get_items().getItem(25).uncheck();
            combo.commitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would be well suited to the new Telerik [RadTreeList](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/dropdowntree.aspx).  You could also look at my custom control, [RadComboTree](http://www.msigman.com/telerik-radcombotree-a-combobox-with-collapsible-items).

> Allow your users to easily browse a multitude of items in hierarchical
>   lists of data with RadDropDownTree for ASP.NET AJAX. Leverage the
>   variety of data binding options, use one of the twenty built-in skins
>   or easily customize the control through templates. Rest assured that
>   the control will work on any browser and device.

[image]

Comment: That does seem like an interesting alternative. However if they wanted to select world continents how would they be able to select the whole group rather than having to select them all individually?